# JQuery not working in ExactTarget landing page

Tags: jquery, marketing-cloud

We have a landing page in ExactTarget that includes form fields for two sets of contact information (mailing address vs. billing address). We have added a check box that allows the user to reuse the mailing address information they entered for the billing address information so they don't have to enter the information twice.  We are using javascript for this.  This works outside of ExactTarget, but not within ExactTarget.  Is there a way to make this work?  Here is the problematic code snippet:

```
<script>
    // make billing same as address
    $('input[name=same]').click(function() {
        //alert('Using the same address');  
        if ($("input[name=same]:checked").is(':checked')) { 
            $('#account_bill_fname').val($('#account_fname').val());
            $('#account_bill_company').val($('#account_company').val());
            $('#account_bill_address1').val($('#account_address1').val());
            $('#account_bill_address2').val($('#account_address2').val());
            $('#account_bill_city').val($('#account_city').val());             
            var state = $('select[name=account_state] option:selected').val(); 
            $('select[name=account_bill_state] option[value=' + state + ']').attr('selected','selected');     
            $('#account_bill_postal').val($('#account_postal').val());
            $('#account_bill_bizphone').val($('#account_bizphone').val());
            $('#account_bill_email').val($('#account_email').val());
        };              
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It appears like this is jQuery, but I'm not seeing where you are calling the `jquery.js` file.  Also - welcome to the community!

Comment: What error are you seeing in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I'm not seeing an error. It works fine outside of ExactTarget. It just doesn't work inside ExactTarget.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not quite sure what errors you are getting from this regarding jQuery.  What is the `<script src=".../jquery.js">` look like as well?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is ET changing your input names, perhaps? If you run `$('input[name=same]');` in your browser's JS console does it match on the field?

Comment: No - it's not really that smart of a system. It's more just an HTML holder - typical issues are easier to debug.

Comment: make sure to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. I've ran into that error before because Salesforce requires HTTPS

Comment: I just saw the following error in IE:  Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 20:24:35 UTC


Message: Expected ')'
Line: 334
Char: 44
Code: 0
URI: http://pages.protective-email.com/Love/


Message: Object expected
Line: 13
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://pages.protective-email.com/Love/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page has a couple errors -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ~ pages.protective-email.com/:334 //This is working now
Uncaught ReferenceError: MM_preloadImages is not defined ~ pages.protective-email.com/:13 // this is in chrome dev tools - looks like a Dreamweaver function that isn't avaialable
```

Couple things I noticed, that you might want to clean up:

- The script in question is loading outside the `<body>` tag, which
  typically could cause issues.
- The script is currently loading with out being inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`.
- The correct syntax for the selector should be `$("INPUT[NAME='SAME']")`.

See if after correcting those items the issue still persists. I can't honestly explain why it would work locally, but something must be more forgiving on your local environment - it really shouldn't.

Your script should look like this -

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // make billing same as address
    $("INPUT[NAME='SAME']").click(function() {
    //alert('Using the same address');  
    if ($("input[name='same']:checked").is(':checked')) { 
      $('#MA_FullName').val($('#FullName').val());
      $('#MA_Company').val($('#Company').val());
      $('#MA_Address1').val($('#Address1').val());
      $('#MA_Address2').val($('#Address2').val());
      $('#MA_City').val($('#City').val());    
      $('#MA_ZIP').val($('#ZIP').val());
      $('#MA_Phone').val($('#Phone').val());
      $('#MA_Email').val($('#Email').val());         
      var state = $("select[name='State'] option:selected").val(); 
      $("select[name='MA_State'] option[value=" + State + "]").attr('selected','selected');     

      };              
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

The code that is on the live site is showing as this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // make billing same as address
    $("INPUT[NAME='SAME']").click(function() {
    //alert('Using the same address');  
    if ($("input[name='same']:checked").is(':checked')) { 
      $('#MA_FullName').val($('#FullName').val());
      $('#MA_Company').val($('#Company').val());
      $('#MA_Address1').val($('#Address1').val());
      $('#MA_Address2').val($('#Address2').val());
      $('#MA_City').val($('#City').val());    
      $('#MA_ZIP').val($('#ZIP').val());
      $('#MA_Phone').val($('#Phone').val());
      $('#MA_Email').val($('#Email').val());         
      var state = $("select[name='State'] option:selected").val(); 
      $("select[name='MA_State'] option[value=" + State + "]").attr('selected','selected');     

      };              
    });
});
```

The reason why it is not working is due to the very first line - `$("INPUT[NAME='SAME']")` will ***never*** match your HTML element, because nothing on the page mathes, as jQuery is case-sensitive.

Not sure why that particular line is all caps, but that needs to be changed to `same` all lower case. That should solve your problem.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/Ap6Su/) to prove the point.

Comment: That is actually what I am using. For some reason, it cut part of the URL off when I pasted it here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you share the landing page url?

Comment: make sure to use **HTTPS** instead of **HTTP**.  I've ran into that error before because Salesforce requires HTTPS

Comment: @amatorVitae This isn't on Salesforce - it's on their product ExactTarget.  It's worth a shot, but I haven't run into this before.

Comment: http://pages.protective-email.com/Love/

Comment: I tried changing it to HTTPS, but it still isn't working. :(

Comment: Thanks Kelly. I modified the page to clean up the items you mentioned, but it still isn't working within ExactTarget. As you can probably tell, I'm not a developer so if you could check to be sure what I did was correct, I would appreciate it. Also, I wasn't sure how to correct the two errors. When I look at the code, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Okay, I put in the code you provided. Still not working, but I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: I can assure jQuery does work in landing pages.  Just have to figure out what is causing your problem here.  It's not with ExactTarget directly though.

Comment: It works! You are wonderful! Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery, and I'm assuming this is used on a VF page.  At first glance, I think that the issue might be with using the reserved variable `$` since Salesforce reserves that variable name for many of their own features.

Whenever I use jQuery, I override the `$`-shortuct by declaring another variable as the shortcut with `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Example:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script>
    var j$=jQuery.noConflict();
    // now use "j$" wherever you would use "$"

    j$(document).ready(function(){

        alert('hi');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't apply, the question is about ExactTarget's landing page solution.

Comment: @amatorVitae - Kelly, thanks for your quick response and follow-up. I updated the post with a jquery tag. Hopefully someone will respond specific to ExactTarget landing pages.  Thanks again.